# AJAX Adding Multiple Events Resetting Id Before Insert

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

In Full Calendar, i have some droppable external items. When i drag and drop one of them and immediately i delete it, it gets deleted, everything works fine. However, when i drop multiple items, such as 2 and when i delete 2 of them, both gets removed from calendar in the view, actually one gets removed from database, if i refresh the page i can see that.

When i check the form input hidden's value which is event's id fetched from database or returned from database as last insert id via ajax, both are the same it seems, actually they are not the same.

I think what i need is, resetting the eventID variable after they got dragged and dropped. I tried to initiliza them as empty, but it doesn't work.

How can i reset their values after ajax submit for the next units, hence keeping that variable to attached to current. Also its a global variable, i think this is the problem.

My Codes:

```
var eventID; // global variable
```

Drop Function:

```
drop: function(date, allDay) { 
var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
        // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
        var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

        // assign it the date that was reported

        copiedEventObject.start = date;

        if($extraEventClass) copiedEventObject['className'] = [$extraEventClass];

        var tempDate = new Date(date);
        copiedEventObject.start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(copiedEventObject.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        eventID = '';
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?=site_url("admin/calendar/add");?>',
            data: 'title='+ copiedEventObject.title,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(newID){
                eventID = newID;
                //copiedEventObject._id = newID;
            }
        });
  calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
            {
                title: copiedEventObject.title,
                start: date,
               //id: copiedEventObject._id,
                id: eventID,
            }),
            true // make the event "stick"
 }
```

Event Click Function:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        if(!eventID){
            eventID = calEvent._id;
        }
        var form = $("<form id='changeName'>" +
            "<h3 class='eventHeader'>Edit</h3>" +
            "</div></form>");
        form.append("<div class='controls'>" +
            "<label class='control-label' for='title'>Name: </label>" +
            "<input class='span3' name='title' autocomplete=off type='text' value='" + calEvent.title + "' />" +
            "</div>");
        form.append("<input type=hidden value='" + eventID + "' /> ");
        form.append("<div class='controls'>" +
            "<button type='submit'> Save </button>");

var div = bootbox.dialog(form,
   [
     {
       "label" : "Delete",
       "callback": function() {
          deleteOrNot = confirm("Sure ??");
            if (deleteOrNot) {
              calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents' , function(ev){
                $.ajax({
                  url: '<?=site_url("admin/calendar/delete");?>',
                  data: 'id='+ eventID,
                  type: "POST"
                });
                 return (ev._id == calEvent._id);
                })
              }
            }
          }
        ]);

        $("#changeName").submit(function() {
            calEvent.title = form.find("input[name=title]").val();
            calEvent.description = form.find("input[name=description]").val();
            calEvent.id = form.find("input[type=hidden]").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?=site_url("admin/calendar/editTitle");?>',
                data: 'title='+ calEvent.title+'&id='+ calEvent.id,
                type: "POST"
            });
            calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', calEvent);
            div.modal("hide");
            return false;
        });
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your delete process...you shouldn't be relying on the global `eventID`, rather just getting the ID from specific event

Change:

```
if(!eventID){
    eventID = calEvent._id;
}
```

To:

```
var  eventID = calEvent._id;
```

I suspect you also have a problem within `drop` by using the global `eventID` when dropping more than one at a time. Would have to see what `// some methods here` does.

What I would suggest is getting rid of the global `eventID` completely. When adding, wait for the id to be returned from server before passing the data to fullCalandar within your success callback

Similarly...within deleteOrNot...should make ajax request first, then only call the `calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents'` within success callback of `$.ajax`. This will give confirmation of ajax success before user sees event removed. If ajax fails, user won't know using your approach

Comment: when i get rid from eventID global variable, the copy object's id can't be set as i've tried. added the methods part also.

Comment: OK...the problem is `AJAX` is asynchronous....move `calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',` inside the success callback , otherwise it fires before ajax has completed

Comment: just have to always think...."make sure database is updated ***before*** updating user interface"

Comment: thank you very much again, nice to have this experience thanks to you.